# Debian agnostic, version agnostic way to configure update preferences in unattended-upgrades

Tags: debian, upgrade, dpkg, unattended-upgrades

I understand the the configuration files for `unattended-upgrades` in which you determine if you want only security upgrades or other upgrades as well, are located in a bit "dynamic" locations that could change between specific debian distros and their versions.

Is there a general command structure to control these in a uniformal, Debian agnostic, version agnostic way? Some command I could learn?

I'm not sure that the following is what I need:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
```

I might miss the association between priority and allowed origins, as in:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

### Update for Stephen

Dear Stephen, if I understood your answer correctly what I should do, due to the hierarchy you describe is to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add in the end of that file:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

This would be the most minimal way to make the change of allowing upgrading of all types of software, given there isn't a command for that.

Comment: By Debian agnostic I mean it can work for all or most Debian oriented distros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APT configuration files are read [in the following order](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.conf.5):

1. the file specified by `APT_CONFIG` if any;
2. files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`;
3. `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Later files override earlier ones, so in practice the best place to put settings is `/etc/apt/apt.conf`; that will override any setting defined in a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`. An alternative which should work well is to use a file named `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99local`, but `/etc/apt/apt.conf` has worked fine for me for this kind of purpose for many years. You can think of this setup as allowing packages to provide default configuration in files in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` containing the local system administrator’s desired configuration.

In your case, you should edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add the following snippet to it:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};
```

You don’t want `-proposed` (which contains packages waiting for approval); you might want `-backports` (which contains packages backported from the current release of Debian), if you use backported packages. `-updates` contains upgrades which aren’t important for security; so you can enable it to get upgrades as they are made available, or disable it to batch upgrades at point releases.

The priority specified in the `dpkg-reconfigure` command doesn’t have any association with allowed origins, it simply determines [which configuration questions are displayed](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debconf/dpkg-reconfigure.8) (and should be unnecessary since `low` is the default for `dpkg-reconfigure`).